# How to fix error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Probuilder' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I keep getting the "Assets\Karting\Scripts\Utilities\MeshCombineUtility.cs(3,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Probuilder' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" on my game that I'm building on top of the default karting minigame, I don't know where the problem originated, anyone has some idea of what could be going on? I already have pro builder installed.

Comment: Does the project use Assembly Definitions and have you maybe not referenced the according one?

Answer (score 1):

[Pro builder](https://unity3d.com/unity/features/worldbuilding/probuilder) is the built in package for model protyping in unity.
You can do window->package manager ->unity built in, to download and import the package.

Comment: I installed it but the error still there, do I need to do something so that my unity recognizes the new package?

Comment: @vittoriobelinelo You probably don’t have it installed right or you might have an old version of unity that doesn’t support the newest version of probilder.